# Problems Blocking Access to Single File with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

So, all I'm attempting to do with this .htaccess file is prevent anybody that isn't the server from being able to view the file e-mails.txt. The server needs access to it for a php script(using fopen). Everything I've read says this should work, but this is preventing any file in the directory, and subdirectories from what I can tell, from being accessible.

```
<Files e-mails.txt>
     Order deny, allow
     Deny from all
</Files>
```

Also, before when .htaccess was similar, it wasn't blocking the entire directory, but it was preventing the .php script to function properly, which is what caused me to delete it, which fixed the .php script but let e-mails.txt be visible to everyone. So then, when I re-created it and used the above code, the entire site/directory is spitting out a 500 error.

Comment: Why not create a directory for files you don't want to serve, lock the directory down, and put that file in it?  That makes a billion times more sense than leaving it in a directory from which files are normally served and trying to exclude just one file.

Comment: Oh, yeah! That makes like 10,000x more sense. I just did that and it works. I'm still a little curious as to why what I had in my .htaccess file didn't work though. Also, I don't get why what was in my .htaccess file was edited? I would understand it if I formatted it wrong, but the way it was edited excludes the Files directive I was using? Anyway, thanks!

Comment: The code you put in the question didn't show at all because you have to space code that contains `<` over by 4 spaces or it becomes invisible. In general, when you post a code block, highlight it and press ctrl+k and it will space it over for you.

Answer (score 0):

May be, you can write a rewrite condition for this file to 404 or 500 error page. This method render impossible access over http.

Comment: But why does this stop all http access? I'm using the files directive. It should only stop traffic going to e-mails.txt

Comment: Ok, another way is, you can move to emails.txt file to "emails" directory and deny access this directory via .htaccess.